# MSAL vs msgraph-sdk-java-auth

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I want to develop a Java Web App to consume some Microsoft Graph Services. According to Azure Portal's "Quick Start" tab, they recommend MSAL to authenticate and call the services (com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.*).

On the other hand, I've found https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java-auth, which offers a nice API to use the services, but the last uptade is from more than a year.

Which should I use? I'm a bit afraid the SDK gets deprecated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at the [dotnet version of this library](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-auth), you'll see it uses MSAL. Whenever the Java msgraph auth library was started, MSAL Java wasn't ready. There's work that needs to be done to align the Java auth library with the dotnet one so it uses MSAL as well. I'd say go ahead and use the Java auth library keeping in mind a few things:

1. It will change as the required work gets done
2. Auth libraries for msgraph SDKs are all in preview and might change in the future
3. There's currently a limitation addressed by this [pull request](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java-auth/pull/29) and that you can workaround as [documented here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/java-spring-webhooks-sample/issues/1)